# Facebook share try to load different description for different articles

Tags: php, facebook, share, facebook-opengraph

When I load information for all articles, the information is loaded but when i try to share it it gets the wrong title, desc and img.

```
$allPost = Post::getAllPageList();
        if (count($allPost)) {
            $meta='';
            foreach ($allPost as $k => $v) {
                $post = new Post($v);
                $fileName = $post->getFirstPic($v);
                $meta .= "<meta property='og:title' content='".$post->getTitle()."' />";
                $meta .= "<meta property='og:description' content='".strip_tags(html_entity_decode($post->getText(),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))."' />";
                $meta .= "<meta property='og:image' content='http://lateevents.com/upload/Post/GalleryBig/$fileName' />";
            }
            echo $meta;
        }
```

When I try to filter the information by article i fails, Facebook gets nothig.

CODE:

```
        $allPost = Post::getAllPageList();
        if (count($allPost)) {
            $meta='';
            foreach ($allPost as $k => $v) {
                if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!=$v)
                    continue;
                $post = new Post($v);
                $fileName = $post->getFirstPic($v);
                $meta .= "<meta property='og:title' content='".$post->getTitle()."' />";
                $meta .= "<meta property='og:description' content='".strip_tags(html_entity_decode($post->getText(),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))."' />";
                $meta .= "<meta property='og:image' content='http://lateevents.com/upload/Post/GalleryBig/$fileName' />";
            }
            echo $meta;
        }
```

The information is actualy loaded correctly but facebook ignores it.

Any ideas?

PS: I see what Facebook gets from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object/).

Comment: Are you sure you're outputting the meta tags in the <head>, where they belong?

Comment: Yes, they are in <head>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in

> if(isset($_GET['id']) && $_GET['id']!=$v)

. For some reason `$_GET['id']` should be assigned to variable.

CODE

```
$allPost = Post::getAllPageList();
        if (count($allPost)) {
            $id=$_GET['id'];
            $meta='';
            foreach ($allPost as $k => $v) {
                if(isset($id) && $id!=$v)
                    continue;
                $post = new Post($v);
                $fileName = $post->getFirstPic($v);
                $meta .= "<meta property='og:title' content='".$post->getTitle()."' />";
                $meta .= "<meta property='og:description' content='".strip_tags(html_entity_decode($post->getText(),ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8'))."' />";
                $meta .= "<meta property='og:image' content='http://lateevents.com/upload/Post/GalleryBig/$fileName' />";
            }
            echo $meta;
        }
```